# Corrupt Ligatures in combination with unicode-math and cleartype fonts

Tags: unicode-math, ligatures

I have a strange problem with ligatures at the bibliography using the combination of unicode-math and windows cleartype fonts(Calibri & Consola).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consola}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document} 
Seattle if dictionary fifty \\
Seattle if dictionary fifty \texttt{Consolafont}
\end{document}
```

Using lualatex, this leads to the following corrupt 'Seattle'-ligature:
[image]

The problem exists only at this combination of consola/calibri font and unicode-math. In annother document, the problem occurs also at the fifty, but not here ?!

Does somebody has an idea how to solve this issue? And is it a unicode-math problem, a lualatex problem, a font problem or something else?

Comment: Just for fun, does this also happen if you write `Seattle` in the text? (because then your MWE does not need `biblatex` and can be simplified a lot. (I cannot test as I don't have access to the fonts)

Comment: No, in textmode everything is correct. I think the problem is the mixture of the different fonts

Comment: Strange, then ought to tag it with `biblatex` as well. Is there something funny in the `.bbl` file?

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, i seldomly use monospace font within regular text... The MWE can defined short, see the update above

Comment: Fails for me with lualatex with the default fontloader but works with a newer, local one.

Comment: What do you mean with "fontloader"?

Comment: The `fontloader-2017-02-11.lua` mentioned in your log. One  can tell luaotfload to use another and I have few. But they also need and adjusted luotfload-letterspace.lua. In any case it means that an newer version of luaotfload would resolve the problem, but it is quite unclear when this will happen ...

Comment: Btw: Consolas seems to be fishy font. See https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/265